# How to migrate from synchronized to ReentrantLock on Java for looping arrays

Tags: java, concurrency

For the below example code, how to migrate from `synchronized` to `ReentrantLock`?

Below is refactored code

```
public final class ControllerCell {

    public final int tableSize;
    private final ObjectCell cells[][];
    private final TGS_ShapeDimension<Integer> cellSize;
    private final float jpeg_quality;

    public static ControllerCell of(float jpeg_quality, int tableSize) {
        return new ControllerCell(jpeg_quality, tableSize);
    }

    private ControllerCell(float jpeg_quality, int tableSize) {
        this.jpeg_quality = jpeg_quality;
        this.tableSize = tableSize;
        cellSize = new TGS_ShapeDimension(0, 0);
        cells = new ObjectCell[tableSize][tableSize];
    }

    final public void processImage(ControllerInput cInput) {
        cellSize.width = cInput.screenSize.width / tableSize;
        cellSize.height = cInput.screenSize.height / tableSize;
        for (var i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < tableSize; j++) {
                if (cells[i][j] == null) {
                    cells[i][j] = new ObjectCell(jpeg_quality);
                }
                var subw = (i == tableSize - 1) ? (cellSize.width + (cInput.screenSize.width % cellSize.width)) : cellSize.width;
                var subh = (j == tableSize - 1) ? (cellSize.height + (cInput.screenSize.height % cellSize.height)) : cellSize.height;
                var subimage = cInput.screenShot().getSubimage(i * cellSize.width, j * cellSize.height, subw, subh);
                synchronized (cells[i][j]) {
                    cells[i][j].update(subimage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

below is the original code. To download [click here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ajaxvnc/files/latest/download)

Class: TileManager

```
/**
 *
 * @author heic
 */
package hk.haha.onet.ajaxvnc;
import java.awt.image.*;
public class TileManager {
    
    private boolean DEBUG = true;
    
    public final int MAX_TILE = 10;
    private Tile tiles[][];
    private int numxtile;
    private int numytile;
    private int tilewidth;
    private int tileheight;
    private int screenwidth;
    private int screenheight;
    
    /** Creates a new instance of TileManager */
    public TileManager() {
        tiles = new Tile[MAX_TILE][MAX_TILE];
        numxtile = MAX_TILE;
        numytile = MAX_TILE;
        setSize(640, 480);
    }
    
    public void setSize(int sw, int sh) {
        screenwidth = sw;
        screenheight = sh;
        tilewidth = screenwidth / numxtile;
        tileheight = screenheight / numytile;
    }
    
    public void processImage(BufferedImage image, int x, int y)
    {
        BufferedImage subimage;
        int subw, subh;
        boolean changed;
        numxtile = x;
        numytile = y;
        setSize(screenwidth, screenheight);
        for (int i=0; i < numxtile; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j < numytile; j++) {
                if (tiles[i][j]==null) tiles[i][j] = new Tile();
                    if (i == numxtile-1) 
                        subw = tilewidth + (screenwidth % tilewidth);
                    else
                        subw = tilewidth;
                    if (j == numytile-1)
                        subh = tileheight + (screenheight % tileheight);
                    else
                        subh = tileheight;
                    subimage = image.getSubimage(i*tilewidth, j*tileheight, subw, subh);
            synchronized (tiles[i][j]) {
                changed = tiles[i][j].updateImage2(subimage);
                if (DEBUG) {
                    if (changed) System.out.println(getClass().getName() + ": [" + i + "," + j + "] Changed. ["+tiles[i][j].fileSize()+"]");
                }
            }
           }
         }    
    }
}
```

Class: Tile

```
/**
 *
 * @author heic
 */
package hk.haha.onet.ajaxvnc;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBuffer;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.awt.image.PixelGrabber;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.zip.Adler32;
import java.util.zip.CheckedOutputStream;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.imageio.stream.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.imageio.metadata.*;
public class Tile {
    
    private boolean DEBUG = false;
    
    private ByteArrayOutputStream stream;
    private Adler32 checksum;
    private long version;
    private boolean dirty;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private static ImageWriter imgwriter;
    private static ImageWriteParam iwp;
    
    /** Creates a new instance of Tile */
    public Tile() {
        stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        checksum = new Adler32();
        version = 0;
        dirty = true;
        width = 0;
        height = 0;
    // create image writer
    Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg");
    imgwriter = (ImageWriter)iter.next();
    iwp = imgwriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
    iwp.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    iwp.setCompressionQuality(Config.jpeg_quality);   // an integer between 0 and 1
    
    
    }
    private IIOMetadata getIIOMetadata(BufferedImage image, ImageWriter imageWriter, ImageWriteParam param) {
        ImageTypeSpecifier spec = ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(image);
        IIOMetadata metadata = imageWriter.getDefaultImageMetadata(spec,param);
        return metadata;
    }
    
    private void writeImage(BufferedImage image, OutputStream outs)
    {
        try {
/*            ImageIO.write(image, "JPG", outs);*/
            width = image.getWidth();
            height = image.getHeight();
        ImageOutputStream ios  = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(outs);

        imgwriter.setOutput(ios);
        IIOMetadata meta = getIIOMetadata(image, imgwriter, iwp);
        imgwriter.write(meta, new IIOImage(image, null, meta), iwp);
        ios.flush();
    
        
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public boolean updateImage2(BufferedImage image)
    {
        long oldsum;
        oldsum = checksum.getValue();
        //calcChecksum(image);
        calcChecksum2(image);
        if (oldsum != checksum.getValue()) {
            if (DEBUG) System.out.println(getClass().getName() + ": Version changed [" + stream.size() +"]");
            stream.reset();
            writeImage(image, stream);
            version++;
            dirty = true;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            if (DEBUG) System.out.println(getClass().getName() + ": Version unchange");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The motivation is to make use of virtual threads in Java 21+. To quote [`JEP 444: Virtual Threads`](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444):

> avoid frequent and long-lived pinning by revising `synchronized` blocks or methods that run frequently and guard potentially long I/O operations to use `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock` instead.

Comment: You would need an array of `ReentrantLock`s equal in size to `cells`.

Comment: I figured that but using one reetrantlock looks already compilcated, now array of that?https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reentrant-lock-java/

Comment: As Louis already said, you need a `ReentrantLock` for each cell – what makes the whole thing unnecessary large. If you really have concurrency on each and every cell, you should stuck with the `synchronized` approach.

Comment: But for Virtual Thread, i need to migrate, or try to find another implementation with structuredscope which will only make things more complicated.

Comment: Can each cell own a lock and lock itself in the update method? Do you really need to lock each cell independently or can you lock the whole image? It’s very hard to answer this question in a useful way without more context.

Comment: I found the original code. it is used to write image to stream, please see TileManager @ https://sourceforge.net/projects/ajaxvnc/files/latest/download

Comment: Please include the definition of the `ControllerInput` class and the class of the elements of the `cells` array.

Comment: @Tim Moore As my project is not complete, I added the original code as is, removing only unrelated functions like getters.

Comment: Why do you protect `cells[i][j].update(subimage);` with `sychronized` but not protect the assignment `cells[i][j] = new ObjectCell(jpeg_quality);`?

Comment: @TugalsanKarabacak I don't really understand this synchronization in the first place. Given you're synchronizing on the elements of the array, not the array itself or some other lock guarding the array, why don't you have `ObjectCell` and `Tile` being responsible for their own thread-safety?

Comment: This synchronization is completely broken anyway. Your loop performs the assignment `cells[i][j] = new ObjectCell(jpeg_quality);` without any synchronization, followed by `synchronized (cells[i][j])` which means, it uses an unpredictable object in case of multiple threads. But for a correct synchronization, all threads must synchronize on the same object. However, there are no multiple threads. This code clearly processes the entire array sequentially, so why do you bother trying to synchronize here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most straightforward way to convert code from `synchronized` to `ReentrantLock`, if you can modify the class being locked, is to add a `ReentrantLock` member to the object that was previously `synchronized`. To simplify the example, given a `Tile` class like this:

```java
public class Tile {
    public void update() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and a usage of it like this:

```java
synchronized (tile) {
    tile.update();
}
```

It can be modified this way:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Tile {
    public final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public void update() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and used like this:

```java
tile.lock.lock();
try {
    tile.update();
} finally {
    tile.lock.unlock();
}
```

If the `Tile` class cannot be modified, you can either keep a parallel array of `ReentrantLock` instances, or refactor to wrap the `Tile` and `ReentrantLock` together in another class.

There are some other things you might want to consider for your use case.

## Avoiding client-side locking

This pattern of the code accessing an object acquiring a lock on it is sometimes known as *client-side locking*, because it is the client of the locked object that is responsible for acquiring the lock, rather than the locked object itself. This practice is often [discouraged](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/LCK11-J.+Avoid+client-side+locking+when+using+classes+that+do+not+commit+to+their+locking+strategy) due to a major drawback: it relies on *all* usages of the object to correctly and consistently implement the locking strategy. This makes it very hard to reason about the thread-safety of the class, as it can only be understood by considering every use of the class throughout the code. As an example of how this can cause a problem: if the code is updated from `synchronized` to using `ReentrantLock` in one place, but not in others, then the mutual exclusion property will be broken.

As an alternative, the `Tile` class could take responsibility for locking itself, documenting its thread-safety guarantees in terms of its properties, rather than its implementation:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Tile {
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public void update() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            // ...
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

It can then be used in a more straightforward way:

```java
tile.update(); // no need to lock here
```

This is a simplified example, and in the real `Tile` class, other methods would also need to be modified to acquire the lock as needed.

## Fine-grained vs. coarse-grained locking

In the case of a composite object, where one object (in this case, `TileManager`) contains a collection of internal objects that are completely encapsulated and not exposed to other classes (in this case, `Tile`), there's a choice to make when operating concurrently on the internal collection: you can either lock each item in the collection independently (fine-grained locking), or you can lock the entire collection (coarse-grained locking). These have tradeoffs, and the best option depends on the specific use case. Fine-grained locking, as in this example, allows multiple threads to concurrently access different parts of the collection, which helps to avoid a long-running process preventing other threads from accessing elements that it isn't currently affecting. The main drawback to be aware of is the risk of deadlock if there is a thread that needs to lock multiple elements at the same time. There is also the potential for different behaviour when there is high contention. The `processImage` method could become blocked several times, waiting to acquire locks on individual tiles. It might be more desirable to allow it to acquire a single coarse-grained lock and complete the iteration of `tiles` without the risk of further blocking. This really depends on the specifics of the application, and must be considered with the context of the other uses of the data.

Answer (score 3):

If you can modify the source code of your `ObjectCell` class, see the [Answer by Tim Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77176727/642706). If not, read on.

If you must protect each cell/tile individually rather than in a group, the solution seems obvious:

When you populate `ObjectCell[][] cells`, you also populate a parallel `ReentrantLock[][] locks`.

```java
if (cells[i][j] == null) {
    cells[i][j] = new ObjectCell(jpeg_quality);
    locks[i][j] = new ReentrantLock();
}
```

Your code:

```java
synchronized (cells[i][j]) 
{
    cells[i][j].update(subimage);
}
```

… becomes:

```java
locks[i][j].lock();
try
{
    cells[i][j].update(subimage);
}
finally
{
    locks[i][j].unlock();
}
```

Comment: In your example, how Java knows which lock is responsible for which cell? Should not we put them inside an object first and make array of them?

Comment: @TugalsanKarabacak ??? That’s exactly what I showed in this Answer: Make an array and populate with `ReentrantLock` objects. Use the same `[i][j]` to access both arrays, the cells array and the locks array.

Comment: I understand now, lock is not about locking a class or function, but only code inside the try scope.